# If $f$ is uniformly continuous on two open sets with a non-empty intersection, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on their union

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, uniform-continuity

There is a problem when I am solving this question:-

> Suppose $a<b<c<d$. Prove that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ and on $(c,d)$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)\cup(c,d)$.

I solve the question like this:
$\forall \epsilon>0$.
As $f$ is uniformly continuous on A, then $\exists\delta_1>0\ni\forall x,y\in (a,b),|x-y|<\delta_1\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

Also, $f$ is uniformly continuous on (c,d), then $\exists\delta_2>0\ni\forall x,y\in (c,d),|x-y|<\delta_2\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

Take $\delta$ = $\min(\delta_1,\delta_2),\forall
x,y\in(a,b)\cup(c,d),|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

But when I see the solution, it is given as

> Take $\delta$ = $\min(\delta_1,\delta_2, c-b)$.
>   Then $\forall x,y \in (a,b)\cup(c,d)$, $|x-y|<\delta \implies x,y \in (a,b) \text{ or } x,y \in (c,d),\text{ and } |x-y|<\delta_1\text{ and }\delta_2$
>   $\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$
>   $\therefore f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)\cup (c,d)$.

But why they take $c-b$ in the expression of $\delta$?

And how does it guarantee that $x,y\in(a,b)$ or $(c,d)$ not something like $x\in(a,b)$ and $y \in (c,d)$ or vice versa?

Why we can't take $x\in(a,b)$ and $y\in(c,d)$ to prove uniform continuity on $(a,b)\cup(c,d)$?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this is very well written for a first question. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x \in (a,b)$ and $y\in (c,d).$ Then $x<b$ which gives $-x>-b$ and $y>c.$ So $|x-y|=y-x>c-b.$ Hence taking $\delta\leq c-b$ guarantees that both $x,y$ are in the same interval.

The reason you can't have both in different intervals is that to apply the two implications you have, you **need** both have them to be in the same interval. If $x \in (a,b)$ and $y \in (c,d),$ then there is no condition that guarantees $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: If $f(x)=1,\;\forall x\in(a,b)$ and $f(x)=0,\;\forall x\in(c,d)$. Then if we take x in (a,b) and y in (c,d) then $|f(x)-f(y)|=1$, so is not uniformly continuous. So we take into account $\delta<c-b$. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Iti $f$ is still uniformly continuous on $(a,b) \cup (c,d),$ since it is uniformly continuous on each of the intervals. You are required to show that when $x,y$ are **very close** to each other, then so are $f(x)$ and $f(y).$ It doesn't matter what happens when they aren't close (which is the case when $x,y$ are in separate intervals).

Comment: Ok. Now I have understood. But I have one more question, if b=c , i.e. (a,b)U(b,d) and function is defined as above in the first comment, then what should be the constraint on $\delta$ to keep x,y in same interval because if we use $\delta< c-b=0$, it will not right?

Comment: @Iti If $b=c,$ then the function you defined is **not** uniformly continuous on $(a,b) \cup (b,d).$ Indeed for any $\delta>0,$ take $x=b-\frac{\delta}{4},y=b+\delta/4,$ then $|x-y|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(y)|=1.$ So your example is a **great** counter-example to show that it is important to take $b<c$ in the statement of the theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not correct because you 
can have $x \in (a,b)$ and $y \in (c,d)$ with $|x-y| <\delta$. This cannot happen if you make $\delta <c-b$.  ( Indeed $x \in (a,b), y \in (c,d)$ implies $y-x >c-b$ because $y>c$ and $x <b$).

Comment: But in the solution given in book they also include (c-b) in the expression $\delta$, I haven't understood it

Comment: See my edited answer.